# How to change keyboard shortcut of "Show location of pointer"?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, configuration, cursor, gnome-tweak-tool

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and in the `gnome-tweak-tool` there is an option called `Show location of pointer`, which upon clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd> makes a little circle thing come off like a ripple from the mouse pointer in order to show its location. Now this is all very useful and that, but I would find it more useful if I could reassign this useful feature to another keyboard shortcut, can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

2021 UPDATE:

Base on the 2 years old discussion [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/merge_requests/521). Starting from GNOME 3.36 (I think) the key binding of `locate-pointer` can be remapped. It lies under `/org/gnome/mutter/locate-pointer-key` key.

To change it (for example remapping it to Right Shift instead):

```sh
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter locate-pointer-key Shift_R
```

Don't forget to enable it before using.

```sh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true
```

Tested on Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'll have to compile your own version of the Gnome settings deamon to accomplish this: [the key value is hard-coded in gsd-locate-pointer.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/mouse/gsd-locate-pointer.c#L382).

Alternatively, you could map an unused key or key combination to [xdotool key 'Control_R'](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/xdotool.1.html).